# Prove this inequality via weighted Jensen inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, computer-algebra-systems, jensen-inequality

The following inequality is derived from this [difficult olympiad problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h464830p2603967).

Suppose $a,b,c$ are three positive real numbers such that $abc = 8$, show that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{a + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{b + 1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{c + 1}} < 2$$

My idea: Note that $\sqrt{x}$ is a concave function on $(0,\infty)$. Let $x,y,z,p,q,r$ be any positive real numbers, then according to weighted Jensen inequality we have
$$\begin{aligned}\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} + \sqrt{z} &= \frac{\sqrt{p^2x}}{p} + \frac{\sqrt{q^2y}}{q} + \frac{\sqrt{r^2z}}{r}\\&\leq\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)(px + qy + rz)}\end{aligned}$$
Let $x = a,y = b,z = c = \frac{8}{ab}$. If we can find appropriate weights $p,q,r$ such that
$$\left(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)(px + qy + rz) < 4$$
then we are done.

Now if I ask Mathematica

```
Reduce[ForAll[a, a > 0, ForAll[b, b > 0, Exists[{p, q, r}, p > 0 && q > 0 && r > 0 && (1/p + 1/q + 1/r) (p/(1 + a) + q/(1 + b) + r/(1 + 8/(a b))) < 4]]]]
```

Mathematica returns `True` in less than 2 seconds(!!). However, it provides no more details other than a truth value.

If I ask instead

```
Reduce[ForAll[a, a > 0, ForAll[b, b > 0, Exists[{p, q, r}, p > 0 && q > 0 && r > 0 && (1/p + 1/q + 1/r) (p/(1 + a) + q/(1 + b) + r/(1 + 8/(a b))) < m]]], m]
```

Mathematical returns `m >= 4`, although using much longer time.

Which algorithm does Mathematica use to verify the proposition? It is certainly not cylindrical algebra, for `CylindricalDecomposition` takes much much longer.

Can we find simple expressions for $p,q,r$ that would complete the proof?

*Update*: I have found a way to carry out quantifier elimination by hand. Therefore the first part of this problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: This problem turned out to be simple enough that quantifier elimination can be carried out "by hand" (with CAS software, of course).

I found a way to solve it.

Remember that the goal is to prove $\forall a > 0, b > 0$ there exists $p > 0, q > 0, r > 0$ such that
$$\left(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} + \frac{1}{r}\right)\left(\frac{1}{a + 1} + \frac{1}{b + 1} + \frac{1}{\frac{8}{ab} + 1}\right) < 4$$
Reducing the LHS (using Mathematica!), we get
$$\frac{(8 p + 8 b p + a b p + a b^2 p + 8 q + 8 a q + a b q + a^2 b q + 
     a b r + a^2 b r + a b^2 r + a^2 b^2 r) (p q + p r + q r)}{(1 + 
     a) (1 + b) (8 + a b) p q r} < 4$$
Now move the denominator to the RHS, and subtract RHS from both sides, we get
$$F(a,b,p,q,r) < 0$$
where $F$ is an enormous polynomial. Now put $q = k_1 p, r = k_2p$, and define $G = F/p^3$. $G$ is also a polynomial, and depends only on $a,b,k_1,k_2$. In fact, $G$ is a quadratic function in $k_1$. Assume that
$$G = Uk_1^2 + Vk_1 + W$$
We can easily see that $U > 0,W > 0$. Therefore the following constraints guarantee the existence of a positive $k_1$ such that $G < 0$:
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}\Delta = V^2 - 4UW &> 0\\V &< 0\end{aligned}\right.$$
Furthermore, this set of inequalities depend only on $a,b,k_2$. From now on we use techniques from algebra.

1) $V$ is a quadratic function in $k_2$. Assume that
$$V = Ak_2^2 + Bk_2 + C$$
We can easily see that $A > 0,B < 0,C > 0,\Delta_V = B^2 - 4AC > 0$. Therefore for any positive $a,b$ there are two positive real numbers $w_1,w_2$ such that
$$V < 0 \Leftrightarrow w_1 < k_2 < w_2$$

2) $\Delta$ is a quartic function in $k_2$. Assume that
$$\Delta = z_0k_2^4 + z_1k_2^3 + z_2k_2^2 + z_3k_2 + z_4$$
We can easily see that $z_0 > 0,z_1 < 0,z_2 > 0,z_3 < 0,z_4 > 0$. Therefore all real roots of $\Delta$ are positive.

3) Let $\Delta'$ be the derivative of $\Delta$ w.r.t. $k_2$. The resultant of $\Delta,\Delta'$ is always positive. Thus $\Delta$ has no repeated roots.

4) Using Sturm's theorem, we can easily see that $\Delta$ has four distinct real roots. Let them be $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$, ordered from smallest to largest.

5) The resultant of $\Delta,V$ is always positive. Thus $\Delta$ and $V$ have no common roots.

6) We now use Tarski's theorem to calculate the Cauchy index of $\Delta'V/\Delta$ and $V'\Delta/V$. It turns out that the Cauchy index of $\Delta'V/\Delta$ is always $0$, and that of $V'\Delta/V$ always $-2$. From here we can deduce that
$$0 < r_1 < w_1 < r_2 < r_3 < w_2 < r_4$$
Therefore if we take any $r_2 < k_2 < r_3$, we can guarantee that $\Delta > 0,V < 0$.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

The Contradiction method works!

Let $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+1}}=p,$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{b+1}}=q$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+1}}=r.$

Thus, $\{p,q,r\}\subset(0,1),$ $\frac{(1-p^2)(1-q^2)(1-r^2)}{p^2q^2r^2}=8$ and we need to prove that:
$$p+q+r<2.$$
Indeed, let $p+q+r\geq2,$ $r=kr'$ such that $k>0$ and $p+q+r'=2$.

Thus, $$p+q+kr'\geq2=p+q+r',$$ which gives $k\geq1.$

Thus, $$8=\frac{(1-p^2)(1-q^2)}{p^2q^2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{k^2r'^2}-1\right)\leq\frac{(1-p^2)(1-q^2)}{p^2q^2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{r'^2}-1\right),$$ which is a contradiction because we'll prove now that
$$8>\frac{(1-p^2)(1-q^2)}{p^2q^2}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{r'^2}-1\right).$$
Indeed, we need to prove that
$$8p^2q^2r'^2>(1-p^2)(1-q^2)(1-r'^2)$$ or
$$512p^2q^2r'^2>((p+q+r')^2-4p^2)((p+q+r')^2-4q^2)((p+q+r')^2-4r'^2)$$ or
$$512p^2q^2r'^2>(3p+q+r')(3q+p+r')(3r'+p+q)(p+q-r')(p+r'-q)(q+r'-p).$$
Now, if $(p+q-r')(p+r'-q)(q+r'-p)\leq0$, so our inequality is true, which says that it's enough to prove it for $(p+q-r')(p+r'-q)(q+r'-p)>0$.

Also, if $p+q-r'<0$ and $p+r'-q<0,$ so $p<0$, which is a contradiction.

Thus, we can assume that $p+q-r'=z>0,$ $p+r'-q=y>0$ and $q+r'-p=x>0$, which gives

$p=\frac{y+z}{2},$ $q=\frac{x+z}{2},$ $r'=\frac{x+y}{2}$ and we need to prove that
$$8(x+y)^2(x+z)^2(y+z)^2>xyz\prod_{cyc}(x+2y+2z),$$
which is obviously true after full expanding.

Done!

It's interesting that even the following is true.

> Let $x$, $y$ and $z$ be non-negative numbers. Prove that:
>   $$125(x+y)^2(x+z)^2(y+z)^2\geq64xyz(x+2y+2z)(2x+y+2z)(2x+2y+z).$$

Comment: I think I've seen a number of solutions to this problem along the contradiction method. I'm specifically interested in solving it via algorithmic approaches. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: There is a related problem, in which $abc = 1$ instead $8$. In this case the maximum is not $4$ but $9/2$. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h17549p119564

Comment: @user2249675 If $abc=\frac{125}{64}$, so the maximum is $2$. It follows from my solution and last inequality.